# "Continuously" or "Continually"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Let's assume that nurses have transferred a patient after surgery to the recovery room a couple of hours ago. The patient has come to already and during this period of time has kept moaning. His/her surgeon comes to check the patient up and asks the head nurse about his/her situation. The nurse wants to describe what has happened to the patient after the recovery. Which one of the choices sounds more correct to be said by the nurse:

> - The patient is ................... restless.

**a.** continuously  [The correct choice in my view] 
**b.** continually

What about the popular sentence below:

> - Life is ................ changing.

**a.** continuously [The correct choice in my view] 
**b.** continually

To me, "**continuous**" means "**without stopping**" and "**continual**" means "**very frequent**".

**Note:** I know there are many possible choices. I just need to know about these two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the web:

> Continual means repeated but with breaks in between; chronic.
>
> Example: The continual problem of our car’s not starting forced us to
>   sell it.
>
> Continuous means without interruption in an unbroken stream of time or
>   space.
>
> Example: The continuous dripping of the faucet drove me crazy.

[Source](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/continual-v-continuous/)

**Continuous = Constant

Continual = Repeated**

However, I think for the first example you should say *The patient is **quite** restless* as being restless is already continual state, with varying degrees of severity (Unless they are restless for 1/2 hour, then sleep 1/2 hour, repeat). I think the severity of the restlessness would be more important here.

For the second example I would also suggest an alternate *Life is **constantly** changing* which, although still means continuously, I think is more idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you very much @Smock. For the first case, please imagine the patient moans repeatedly and sometimes for a couple of minutes he falls asleep, and then he/she suddenly wakes up and keeps moaning for a long time (around 15-20 minutes) again. According to your distinction, I think, "**continual**" is the correct option for the first scenario. And as you mentioned and I thought before posting the thread, for the second case "**continuous**" is the correct choice.

Comment: yes if there's a break between bouts of restlessness, then it would be continual restlessness